# FQL Query for facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql

Iam getting all my friends as an array using

```
$graph_url = "https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?access_token=" . $access_token .
 "&query=SELECT+uid,name,work.position.name+FROM+user+WHERE+uid+IN+
 (SELECT+uid2+FROM+friend+WHERE+uid1+=+me())&format=json";
```

And I want to put a condition to fetch the friends whose work position's name is 'dev'.I had try with `FQL` like

```
$graph_url = "https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?access_token=" . $access_token .
 "&query=SELECT+uid,name,work.position.name+FROM+user+WHERE+uid+IN+
(SELECT+uid2+FROM+friend+WHERE+uid1+=+me())+AND+strpos(work.position.name,'dev')>=0&format=json";
```

But it results me empty array even some of them satisfying the condition.Can anyone suggest me the correct way to approach this..Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

This has been tried to be achieved by several other people as well, see

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17382739/how-to-use-strpos-in-fql-query

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18115546/strpos-in-fql-query

I assume that you cannot use strpos() on fields which contain an array and not an object (which you can reference via object.subobject.field).

"Proof" of my suspicion: If you try to search your friends current locations (which is a subobject of the user object, and not an array), it works:

```
SELECT uid,name,current_location FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) and strpos(current_location.city, 'M') = 0
```

There, I search for all my friends living in a city starting with "M".

Ultimately, you could also parse the resuls on the client side if FQL cannot solve your problem.

And, by the way, I think you should use another endpoint for your FQL queries:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=...
```

Comment: Like I wrote, there's none afaik, and suggested that you parse the results on your side!

Comment: Means getting all the data then need to search as an array..?

Comment: Yes, you need to loop through all your users, and have another loop on user level through the "work" array to search for "dev" in the position.name field.

Comment: Yah I have that Idea,but Suppose I have 1,00,000 friends ,then it wont be the better option right.

Comment: Maybe, but there's no other way in my opinion, so how you want to do it if FQL itself doesn't provide the functionality you want? And having 1m friends isn't likely, I guess the average user has around 150-200.

Answer (score -1):

You can use strpos & lower on some subset of data you already have with indexable field.

In your example you don't have indexable field so ur getting empty array.

```
SELECT uid,name,work.position.name  FROM user WHERE uid IN 
(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND work.position.name
```

This fql statement gives list of friends who has given value for work.position.name, then apply conditions on this json object .