# Facebook FQL query returns no results for language field

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

Facebook FQL query returns no results for languages field if there is a clause specifying languages id or name. If there is no WHERE clause for languages then all fields are returned.

```
SELECT uid,name,languages.name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND (strpos(lower(languages.name), lower("English")) >= 0)
```

See the following link for an example:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20uid%2Cname%2Clanguages.name%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid%20IN%20(SELECT%20uid2%20FROM%20friend%20WHERE%20uid1%20%3D%20me())%20AND%20(strpos(lower(languages.name)%2C%20lower(%22English%22))%20%3E%3D%200)%20

I have had no problems with other fields or FQL queries. All permissions are requested for authorization token.

Comment: What do you mean `if it is filtered`

Comment: AND (strpos(lower(languages.name), lower("English")) >= 0) meaning only return results WHERE languages equals "English".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you can't "filter" on fields containing array, filtering on fields containing objects works as you sketched out. I don't think this is documented in the Facbook API docs.

See my answer here as well: [FQL Query for facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22113776/fql-query-for-facebook/22149402#22149402)

Comment: I will accept that it can't be done by FQL query and use Graph API instead. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, but how do you filter via Graph API?

Comment: Parse the response Object data. Using nested for loops to create a flat Object for each field you are requesting (education, languages and work): languageName.push(friends[i].languages[j].name); createFlatObject(languages, languageName, friends[i].id);

Comment: Yeah, but that's filtering in your application and not the Graph API itself... But great that it works!